# Creating a drag event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dom-events

How would you simulate a dragevent on a particular element? Here is what I tried, but I keep getting a `e.dataTransfer is null` error when my event handler receives the event.

```
var event = document.createEvent('DragEvents');
event.initEvent('dragstart', true, false);
document.getElementById('test').dispatchEvent(event);
```

When I inspect the event from the event handler `dataTransfer` is a property if you use `createEvent('DragEvents')` instead of say `createEvent('Events')` but the property is null.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Also, I believe you need 'DragEvent', using the plural version causes an error.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan the short answer is I figured out and it isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document.createEvent('event')` is being [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent). The new [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) doesn't work because the [`DragEvent` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/DragEvent) is not meant for actual use.

Check [dataTransfer is null when creating drag event programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867245/datatransfer-is-null-when-creating-drag-event-programmatically) for a similar question .